# shell script: bad interpreter: No such file or directory when using pwd

Tags: bash, unix, pwd

I want to go through the files in a directory with a for loop but this comes up.

```
echo: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

code:

```
#!/bin/bash
count=0
dir=`pwd`
echo "$dir"
FILES=`ls $dir`
for file in $FILES
do
 if [ -f $file ]
 then
  count=$(($count + 1))
 fi
done
echo $count
```

Comment: the first echo is just to show the directory
the last one is for the counter

Comment: Did you actually copy/paste your code? What you have there has a syntax error on the `if` line.

Comment: just fixed the missing empty space.. same error occurs

Comment: [Don't use `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) for this kind of file processing. Use [globbing](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/globbingref.html) instead: `for file in *; do ...`

Comment: faced the same issue. Created a new text file and renamed it to blah.sh.Edited it gvim to include #! /bin/sh and my commands.While runnin g on shell the  "bad interpreter: No such file or directory" error was observed. Then deleted the file and created a similar file using vi editor in the shell and added the same set of line as in previous script and this time it worked without any fuss.

Comment: @bharath maybe something similar to this happened to you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2841593/bash-script-bad-interpreter/52442368#52442368  file looks ok but "Stale file handle" file system gone a bit funny.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bash script: bad interpreter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2841593/608639)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Better do :

```
#!/bin/bash
count=0
dir="$PWD"
echo "$dir"

for file in "$dir"/*
do
 if [[ -f $file ]]
 then
  ((count++))
 fi
done
echo $count
```

or a simplest/shortest solution :

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "$PWD"

for file; do
 [[ -f $file ]] && ((count++))
done

echo $count
```

Comment: Thank you for the help i redid the code in another file and fixed the if[] .. my guess is that the original file was corrupted

Comment: In this case `"$dir"/*` could be abbreviated to `./*` or just `*` since the variable contains the current working directory.

Comment: See my new `simplest/shortest solution`

Answer (score 38):

I had the same problem. Removing `#!/bin/bash` did the trick for me. It seems that is not necessary to add where bash is located, since it is on the system path.

I found another solution [here](https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/108534/cli-configuration-issue-bad-interpreter-no-such-file-or-directory-bin-bash-not-found). Change

`#!/bin/bash`

for

`#!/usr/bin/bash`

Comment: This will lead to errors on other systems. For instance, your 2nd ["shebang line"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) doesn't work on Centos 6.

Comment: This solution worked for me!

Answer (score 14):

The `echo: bad interpreter: No such file or directory` is most likely coming from the first line, `#!...` which is called [shebang line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)).

### About the `#!...` line

This line hints the shell what interpreter to use to run the file. That can be e.g. `bash`, or `sh` (which is (roughly) a subset so a lot of things won't work), or basically anything that can execute the file content - Perl, Python, Ruby, Groovy...

The line points the system in cases like calling the script directly when it's executable:

```
./myScript.sh
```

It is also often used by editors to recognize the right syntax highlighting when the file has no suffix - for instance, Gedit does that.

### Solution

To override the line, feed the script to Bash as a parameter:

```
bash myScript.sh
```

Or, you can 'source' it, which means, from within a Bash shell, do either of

```
source myScript.sh
. myScript.sh
```

which will work (roughly) as if you pasted the commands yourself.

Comment: Overriding our sourcing instead are both problematic. You want to fix the shebang so it points to the right place. Sourcing has different semantics and is often not safe unless you separately run it in a subshell.

Comment: @tripleee, Fixing the shebang line is pointless if the script is supposed to be distributed. You never know where the interpreter will reside.

Comment: Then you need an installer, or something like `#!/usr/bin/env bash`. The basic point remains; `source` does something different than running a script in a separate process, and is not safe unless you have inspected the script to make sure it works correctly when sourced, too.

Comment: @tripleee, that's right, but in the context of this question, the OP probably wants to know about that possibility. Of course, downloading a random script from gist and sourcing it is not a good idea :)

Answer (score 6):

I have just come across the same issue and found that my error was in my first line, having

```
#!bin/bash
```

instead of

```
#!/bin/bash
```

Answer (score 5):

In my case the bash script was created on a Windows PC which added a carriage return character in front of every line feed. \x0D\x0A instead of just \x0A. I replaced all the CRLF with just LF using the `sed` and my script works now.

```
sed -i 's//\r/\n//\n/g' /path/to/file.sh
```

Comment: I think I am having the same problem, I keep seeing "\r" not found instances. Could you tell me how to implement this with the sed command?

Comment: @DNAngel `sed -i 's//\r/\n//\n/g' /path/to/file.sh'

Comment: FOr more details, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39527571/are-shell-scripts-sensitive-to-encoding-and-line-endings

Comment: If you are a vimer, `set fileformat=unix` is an another answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you did use Homebrew to install BASH,

Removing the
`#!/bin/bash`
will be suffice.

Comment: Removing the shebang is very dubious advice. Maybe it needs editing, but completely removing it will have unintended consequences on many systems.

Answer (score 2):

I have followed the steps from the following link and issue has been resolved.

Ref link: [script error - bad interpreter](https://alvinalexander.com/blog/post/linux-unix/shell-script-error-bad-interpreter-no-such-file)
Actually, there was an extra **^M** symbol at the end of each line. So, after the removal of that, it worked fine for me.

Hope it helps!

Comment: This duplicates the answer by fahadash from over a year earlier.

Answer (score 2):

This issue could also occur when the file is not in unix format.. try running dos2unix againts the file and try again.

Answer (score 1):

That's a strange error to be getting.  I recommend trying to find the source of the error.

One thing is to check the pwd command.

```
type pwd
```

Make sure it's /usr/bin/pwd or /bin/pwd, and verify it's not a script:

```
file /usr/bin/pwd
```

If it is a script, I bet it starts with

```
#!echo
```

Comment: `pwd` is a bash builtin: `type -a pwd`

Comment: Usually is, true.  Something's causing the "echo: bad interpreter: No such file or directory".  The only way I've ever seen "Bad interpreter" before is an exec of a shell script with a bad path in the `#!/path` line.

Answer (score 1):

You can find where bash is located using command

```
whereis bash
```

and you can copy the bash path to the path where you are seeing bad-interpreter error.

Answer (score 0):

so, if you change your username group priority from username to root, you should change

```
#!/user/bin/bash
```

to

```
#!/bin/bash
```

check your user group (my username is rommi)

```
$ groups rommi
```

this command will output:

```
rommi : root adm cdrom sudo dip plugdev lxd lpadmin sambashare
```

since my username group priority is set to root, i should change my script to

```
#!/bin/bash
```

i change the priority group using:

```
sudo usermod -g root rommi
```

if `groups rommi` command outputs:

```
rommi : rommi adm cdrom sudo dip plugdev lxd lpadmin sambashare
```

then my script should use `#!/usr/bin/bash`

fail make this changes will resutl in `bad interpreter: No such file or directory` error

Answer (score 0):

Solutions provided above mostly work, but changing

```
#!/bin/bash
```

to

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
```

is not always feasible. Because you dont know how many location this shebang is being called. One simple hack is to create a symlink. Get location of current bash.

```
which bash
/usr/bin/bash
```

Create a soft link

```
ln -s /usr/bin/bash /bin/bash
```

It should work like a charm.