# Running a Bash script results in 'Bad interpreter: No such file or directory' error

Tags: linux, bash, shell, file-permissions

I did found questions on

**Bad interpreter: No such file or directory thing on SO**.

My issue is also solved when I changed the script from

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
echo -e "\t\t\e[92mHello from the Test Script!\e[39m"
```

to:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo -e "\t\t\e[92mHello from the Test Script!\e[39m"
```

after 
I did the first line change from looking an answer here.

[Shell script: Bad interpreter.No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15735541/shell-script-bad-interpreter-no-such-file-or-directory-when-using-pwd)

I can not understand why removing the /usr from the first line helps.

P.S.**I am learning about linux file permissions and I was unable to execute my file even after changing the permission using '755'.
So, please if anyone can explain me this.Thanks in advance.:)**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bash script: bad interpreter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2841593/608639)

Comment: Why was this voted down?  I have voted it up as although the english could be better, it is understandable enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On your system, the `bash` shell lives in `/bin/bash` and not `/usr/bin/bash`.

The path after the `!` should be the path to an executable that will be passed the contents of the script as an argument.

You can read more about this at [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix))

As for the second part of your question; it would not have mattered what the permissions are; as the file was pointing to a bad interpreter.

For more on unix file permissions, I suggest reading [this entry on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_system_permissions).

Answer (score 1):

That's because there is no bash binary at `/usr/bin/bash` and the correct path for bash is `/bin/bash`.

The `#!` line at the top of scripts, called the shebang, determines what program (sh, bash, ruby, perl, python, etc.) is used for running the script.

This post covers this topic well:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/87560/does-the-shebang-determine-the-shell-which-runs-the-script

Answer (score 1):

In my case adding `sh` before script name solved the issue.

Comment: What this did was override the shebang `#!/usr/bin/bash` (the shebang is used to specify the interpreter) and explicitly execute the script with the `sh`ell (`/bin/sh`).  `which sh` will tell you that this is indeed the path.  Similarly for `which bash`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also call your script by adding "./" at the beginning in case you call it from the local directory. The other solution is to call it by specifying its full path.

Comment: This will make no difference as the shebang (`#!/usr/bin/bash`) is still the (erroneous) interpreter of the script.  This approach is used when you are in the directory a script is in.  `$PATH` will not (**should not**) contain '.' (ie. the current directory).  Thus with `./script.sh` you are saying "execute this script in the currrent directory".