# Bad interpreter: No such file or directory on .sh script

Tags: php, linux, sh

Heres the code that return me a bad interpreter when running from terminal in Linux:

```
#!/bin/bash

for dir in test/*/
do
./install_module.php $dir
done

sass test/Style/test.scss:themes/ModernAqua/css/test.css --style compressed
echo "Sass styles regenerated"
```

Comment: Add `-x` to the `#!` line so you can tell which command causes the error. I suspect it's `./install_module.php`; take a look at its first line.

Comment: Does `/bin/bash` exists? How do you execute your script? What are its permissions?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bash script: bad interpreter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2841593/bash-script-bad-interpreter)

Comment: I'm root user. The script is in read and write permission. ./install_all_modules.sh: ./install_module.php: /usr/bin/php: bad interpreter: No such file or directory

Comment: By the look of that error, it can't find `php` in `/usr/bin/php`. Where is your `php`? You can do `which php` to see if it is in your path and then change the `/usr/bin/php` to reflect the correct path.

Answer (score 1):

Most probably, your `install_module.php` has a `#!` directive for an interpreter that is not installed (or is installed somewhere else.) Locate the `php` binary (which most probably what this script needs) and correct that directive.

Also, by running your outer script with `-x` parameter to `bash` will provide more information *where* exactly the problem is.