# bin bash bad interpreter

Tags: bash, unix, terminal, bin

```
#! bin/bash
mkdir ~/folder
while [ $brojac -le 5]
do
mkdir ~/folder/zad"$brojac"
brojac = $(( brojac+1 ))
done
```

this is my shellscript,but when I want to run it in terminal, I receive this error

```
mint@mint ~ $ ./prvi.sh
bash: ./prvi.sh: bin/bash: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
mint@mint ~ $
```

Comment: And now there still is problem http://upload.slike.com/slike/2014/08/1408724580-646-x-679px-drugi.png

Comment: Your variable is empty and `[` (unlike `((` does not assume 0 by default).

Comment: variable brojac?  if i write brojac = 0, it is still an error

Comment: See the comments in @glennjackman's answer script.

Comment: `#! bin/bash` looks wrong. Perhaps `#!/usr/bin/env bash` would work better. Possible duplicate of [Bash script: bad interpreter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2841593/608639)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Small errors in your script:

1. $brojac is unassigned, so your integer comparison fails. Assign it an initial value to fix.
2. '[' calls test, so you need spaces around opening and closing braces.
3. You can't have spaces around your equal sign when assigning a value.

Your script, updated:

```
#!/bin/bash
mkdir ~/folder
brojac=0
while [ $brojac -le 5 ]
do
    mkdir ~/folder/zad"$brojac"
    brojac=$(( brojac+1 ))
done
```

Answer (score 5):

It should be

```
#!/bin/bash
```

(first slash)

Comment: And there is still a problem, http://upload.slike.com/slike/2014/08/1408724580-646-x-679px-drugi.png
unary operator

Comment: @StipeViskov If you have a new question, it's better to post a new question rather than asking a follow-up on your existing question (however convenient that seems).

Answer (score 2):

```
#!/bin/bash
mkdir ~/folder
brojac=0
while [ "$brojac" -le 5 ]    # with [...], need to quote vars and spaces around [ and ]
do
  mkdir ~/folder/zad"$brojac"
  brojac=$(( brojac+1 ))     # cannot have spaces around =
done
```

I would write:

```
for ((i=0; i<=5, i++)); do
    mkdir -p ~/folder/zad$i
done
```

Comment: I need to write it with while loop

Comment: This first solution my terminal brings error line 3: [: : integer expression expected
mint@mint ~ $

Answer (score 1):

Or with an simple

```
mkdir -p ~/folder/zad{1..5}
```

if you want `zad1, zad2 .. zad5`

or

```
mkdir -p ~/folder/zad{,1..5}
```

if you want `zad, zad1, zad2 .. zad5`