# "/bin/bash^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory" error when executing a bash script from a cron job

Tags: mysql, linux, bash, cron

***Restore_DB.sh*** :-

```
#!/bin/bash
mysql -u user -ppassword DB_name < /home/A/B/SQL_File.sql
```

I used the above code to restore a MySQL database from a cron job but I'm getting the bellow error

```
/usr/local/cpanel/bin/jailshell: /home/A/B/Restore_DB.sh: /bin/bash^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

This is the cron job command I used:-

```
/home/A/B/Restore_DB.sh
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [./configure : /bin/sh^M : bad interpreter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2920416/configure-bin-shm-bad-interpreter)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bash script: bad interpreter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2841593/608639)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

his looks like a problem with different line end encodings on unixoid and MS-Windows like systems.

Use the line ending `\n` which is native to unixoid systems, not the MS-Windows style. That one holds an extra character which is typically displayed like what you see in the error message (`^M`).

You can take a closer look at the line in question by using a hexeditor. This allows you to see exactly what non-printable characters are used inside a string.

Comment: Can you please give me an example how to use \n?

Comment: Just use a normal `Return` which produces a linebreak. You just have to make sure that you told the editor to use normal unixoid line breaks (unix style). Or use some stripping utility like what @stefreak suggested. Though that sounds like overhead to me, considering you just want to type a linebreak :-) Or, as mentioned above, use a hexeditor. It allows both to verify _and_ to change the string. You can easily spot and remove the offending character. It is displayed like this: 0x10 0x13. Here 0x10 is the `\n` and 0x13 is the `\r` which you do not want there.

Answer (score 6):

Try if dos2unix can fix your file:

```
$ dos2unix /home/A/B/Restore_DB.sh
```

If dos2unix does not exist yet, you can install it with your distribution's package manager.

The problem is the newline encoding, Windows/DOS encodes newlines differently than Unix.

- Unix newline sequence: `\n` (only line feed character)
- Windows newline sequence: `\r\n` (2 characters, carriage return and line feed)

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#Representations

Answer (score 2):

I just ran into this on OS X and noticed dos2unix is available as a brew formula:

```
brew install dos2unix
```

Answer (score 0):

`yum install dos2unix`

works like a charm !!!!

Comment: While this leads to the right path (but how do you know that `yum` is the right package management tool for the submitter?), a bit more explanation (of the cause and fix) would be helpful.