# IE 9 inserts line break as \r\n but IE 11 inserts line break as \n

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, newline

I have a text area in my web application in which I write text with new lines in them

e.g.

```
abc
abc
```

When I save it using java into SQL server IE9 browser reads the text in text area as `abc\r\nabc` but when I save with IE11 it reads text area as `abc\nabc`

Why is it so? Is there a difference in new line rendering of these browsers?

Comment: It's IE, you shouldn't even be surprised.

Comment: LOL :) yes that's correct :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IE9 uses Windows newlines ("\r\n"), while IE11 uses POSIX newlines ("\n").
You need to normalize these anyway, because Linux/Unix systems always use \n.

Usually, you can assume that \r does not disturb, so you can normalize to \r\n, for which a line should display on a new line in all browsers.

As a sidenote, if you'd save Linux shell scripts, then this would matter, because it would interprete \r [as part of the shell interpreter's name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2841593/bash-script-bad-interpreter).

Comment: Thanks! a lot! That answers my questions.