# -bash: script.sh: /usr/bin/ksh: bad interpreter: Permission denied

Tags: linux, bash

I have some problems with ksh.
Logs says we don't have permission to access to ksh.
All rights are 777 and we did the symbolic link into /usr/bin/

In /usr/bin :

```
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root          8 Feb  2 10:29 ksh -> /bin/ksh
```

In /bin

```
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root      21 Dec 23 11:15 ksh -> /etc/alternatives/ksh
```

In /etc/alternatives

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 8 Feb  2 10:01 /etc/alternatives/ksh -> /usr/bin
```

Did something go wrong during installation ?

It's quite critical for me, thanks for you help !

Comment: Everything worked for the symbolic link, it's not the problem.

Comment: [Bash script: bad interpreter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2841593/608639)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going through your question:

- having 777 right in any unix system exposes a huge risk, an attacker simply overwrite your executables to include a keylogger for example, so this should be avoided most of the cases. Using 755 is suitable for most of the executables instead.
- alternatives is a pretty standard linux solution for having more than one alternative for a particular executable in this case ksh
- I think you have to fix your script by pointing it to either /bin/ksh or /bin/ksh93

Here is the ksh installation of my system for reference:

```
[root@ ~]# which ksh
/bin/ksh
[root@ ~]# ls -larth /bin/ksh
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 21 Feb  2 10:21 /bin/ksh -> /etc/alternatives/ksh
[root@ ~]# ls -alrth /etc/alternatives/ksh
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Feb  2 10:21 /etc/alternatives/ksh -> /bin/ksh93
[root@ ~]# ls -alrth /bin/ksh93
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1.5M Nov  3 14:02 /bin/ksh93
```

Answer (score 0):

Try install ksh utility on your System.
In terminal: `yum install ksh` ---> For Redhat based System.