# how to rename all the files in a directory with the current date in linux

Tags: linux, bash

I'm trying to rename all the files in a directory called level6 with the current date as YYYY-MM-DD form using bash shell script

For example a file named "lab" , it will be changed to"2021-4-4-lab"

I tried the following script :

```sh
#!/bin/bash
DAY=$(date +%F)
cd /home/Frank/level6

for FILE in *.txt
 do
mv $FILE ${DAY}-${FILE}
 done
```

but it gives me the error when I try to execute the script :

> bash: ./rn.sh: bin/bash: bad interpreter: No such file or directory

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bash script: bad interpreter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2841593/bash-script-bad-interpreter)

Comment: You may find `+%Y%m%d` easier to work with in the long run (none of those pesky `'-'`s in the filename and all...)

Answer (score -1):

It's an issue with line endings. Run dos2unix <your file path>. And try again. If you get a command not found error, install it with the below command.

```
$ sudo apt-get install dos2unix -y
```

Also, change the file like this,

```sh
#!/bin/bash
DAY=$(date +%F)
cd /home/Frank/level6

for FILE in *.txt
 do
    mv "$FILE" "${DAY}-${FILE}"
 done
```